# How to avoid namespace collision when including identical XHTML JSF 2.0 files

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, facelets

In my JSF 2.0 project, I get a name-space collision when I include two identical XHTML files in a single parent XHTML file. My goal is to create a dashboard of identical controls on a single page, with each control representing a separate context.

For example, in the following JSF file, called `parent.xhtml` (say), I include two "dashboard" facelets:

```
<ui:define name="body">
    <p:panel id="ONE"  >
        <ui:include src="raceboardunit.xhtml"/>
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="TWO" >
        <ui:include src="raceboardunit.xhtml"/>
    </p:panel>
</ui:define>
```

To be simple, say the child facelet "raceboardunit.xhtml" is the following:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

    <p:panel header="Dashboard" >
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="Event" for="idEvent}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#raceBoardController.name}" id="idEvent" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</ui:composition>
```

The problem is the collision involving the output label **id="idEvent"**, since in the `parent.xhtml` file, the two inclusions of the child facelet have an identical named component.

The error is reported as: `Component ID idEvent has already been found in the view.`

The reason for the error is obvious, but *what is the best way to include a variable number of identical components in a JSF 2.0 application that maximises code reuse*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest but ugliest way is to wrap it in a [`<f:subview>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/subview.html) which basically introduces a new [`UINamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) layer.

```html
<p:panel id="ONE">
    <f:subview id="board1">
        <ui:include src="raceboardunit.xhtml"/>
    </f:subview>
</p:panel>
<p:panel id="TWO">
    <f:subview id="board2">
        <ui:include src="raceboardunit.xhtml"/>
    </f:subview>
</p:panel>
```

Better is to make it a tag file or a composite component instead.

Here's an example of how it can look like as a tag file:

```html
<p:panel id="ONE">
    <my:raceboardunit id="board1" />
</p:panel>
<p:panel id="TWO">
    <my:raceboardunit id="board2" />
</p:panel>
```

with in tag file

```html
<h:outputLabel for="#{id}_idEvent" value="Event" />
<h:inputText id="#{id}_idEvent" value="#{raceBoardController.name}" />
```

*(I think that you oversimplified the example in the question too much that it made no sense; a label referring another label? So I've also fixed it so that it makes somewhat sense.)*

A composite component has basically the same usage as a tag file, but is by itself implicitly already an `UINamingContainer`, so you wouldn't need to manually prefix the IDs inside the composite component implementation.

```html
<h:outputLabel for="idEvent" value="Event" />
<h:inputText id="idEvent" value="#{raceBoardController.name}" />
```

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. This nailed it for me. BTW, my label referring to label example does make sense in the context of my app, but you're right - I should have adapted it better for the purposes here.